# php pdo login failure

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, passwords

I've followed an online tutorial for a simple php login and registration script, but when I tried to login it just failed, brought up my error message "login failed. please try again, or register". The registration page works in the sense that it creates a new entry in the database, but it won't redirect to the given redirection page either. Here is the code:

**class.user.php** (this is included once in the config file)

```
<?php

class USER {
private $db_user;

function __construct($db) {
    $this->db_user = $db;
}

public function register($u_fname,$u_lname,$u_email,$u_tel,$uname,$upass) {

    try {

        $new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $stmt = $this->db_user->prepare("INSERT INTO users(user,pass,first_name,last_name,telephone,email) VALUES(:user, :pass, :fname, :lname, :tel, :email)");

        $stmt->bindparam(":user", $uname);
       $stmt->bindparam(":pass", $new_password);
       $stmt->bindparam(":email", $u_email);
       $stmt->bindparam(":fname", $u_fname);
       $stmt->bindparam(":lname", $u_lname);
       $stmt->bindparam(":tel", $u_tel);          
       $stmt->execute();

       return $stmt;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function login($uname, $upass) {

    try {

        $stmt = $this->db_user->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user=:user LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->execute(array(':user'=>$uname));
        $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['pass'])) {
                $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['id'];
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function is_loggedin() {
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_session'])) {
        return true;
    }
}

public function logout() {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['user_session']);
    return true;
}
}
?>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
$page_title = "Love Deals Login";
require('inc/connect/config.php');
include('inc/header.php');

if($user->is_loggedin()!="") {
$user->redirect('home.php');
}

if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
$uname = $_POST['txt_uname'];
$upass = $_POST['txt_upass'];

if($user->login($uname,$upass)) {
    $user->redirect('home.php');
} else {
    $error = "Login failed. Please try again, or register";
}
}

?>

<div class="container" style="padding: 100px 0 0 0;">
<div class="form-container">
    <form method="post" id="login">
        <h3>Please login</h3>
        <?php if(isset($error)) {
            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> &nbsp; <?php echo $error; ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 login">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt_uname" placeholder="Username" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 login">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="txt_upass" placeholder="Password" required />
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 login">
            <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i>&nbsp;Login</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3" style="text-align: center;">
            <label>Don't have an account yet? <a href="signup.php">Register now</a></label>
        </div>
    </form>
 </div>
</div>

<footer class="navbar-fixed-bottom search-footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

<?php include('inc/footer.php'); ?>
```

**signup.php**

```
<?php
$page_title = "Love Deals Register";
require('inc/connect/config.php');
include('inc/header.php');

if($user->is_loggedin()!="") {
$user->redirect('home.php');
}

if(isset($_POST['signup'])) {
$u_fname = trim($_POST['sign_fname']);
$u_lname = trim($_POST['sign_lname']);
$u_tel = trim($_POST['sign_tel']);
$u_email = trim($_POST['sign_email']);
$uname = trim($_POST['sign_uname']);
$upass = trim($_POST['sign_upass']);

if($u_fname=="") {
    $error[] = "please provide first name";
} else if ($u_lname=="") {
    $error[] = "please provide last name";
} else if($u_tel=="") {
    $error[] = "please provide contact number";
} else if($u_email=="") {
    $error[] = "please provide an email address";
} else if(!filter_var($u_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $error[] = "please provide a valid email address";
} else if($uname=="") {
    $error[] = "please provide username";
} else if($upass=="") {
    $error[] = "please provide password";
} else if(strlen($upass) < 8) {
    $error[] = "Password must be at least 8 characters";
} else {

    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT user FROM users WHERE user=:uname");
        $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname));
        $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($row['user']==$uname) {
            $error[] = "sorry, username already taken! please choose another";
        } else {
            if($user->register($u_fname,$u_lname,$u_tel,$u_email,$uname,$upass)) {
                $user->redirect('signup.php?joined');
            }
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
}

?>

<div class="container" style="padding: 100px 0 0 0;">
<div class="form container">
    <form method="post" id="signup">
        <h3>Register</h3>
        <?php if(isset($error)) {
            foreach($error as $error) {
                ?>
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> &nbsp; <?php echo $error; ?>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
        } else if(isset($_GET['joined'])) {
            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-info">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i> &nbsp; Thanks! You are now registered. <a href="login.php">Login</a>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 login">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sign_fname" placeholder="First Name" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 login">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sign_lname" placeholder="Last Name" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 login">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sign_tel" placeholder="Contact Number" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 login">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sign_email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php if(isset($error)){echo $umail;}?>" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 login">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sign_uname" placeholder="Username" value="<?php if(isset($error)){echo $uname;}?>" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 login">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="sign_upass" placeholder="Password" required />
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary center-block" name="signup">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-open-file"></i>&nbsp;Register</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3" style="text-align: center;">
            <label>Already have an account? <a href="login.php">Login</a></label>
        </div>
    </form>
 </div>
</div>


<footer class="navbar-fixed-bottom search-footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

<?php include('inc/footer.php'); ?>
```

and finally, **home.php**

```
<?php
$page_title = "Love Deals User Home";
require('inc/connect/config.php');
include('inc/header.php');

if(!$user->is_loggedin()) {
$user->redirect('login.php');
}
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=:user_id");
$stmt->execute(array(":user_id"=>$user_id));
$userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<div class="container" style="padding: 100px 0 0 0;">
<h3>welcome back <?php print($userRow['user']); ?></h3>
</div>
<div>
<label><a href="logout.php?logout=true"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"> logout</a></label>
</div>
```

I just can't see where I have a gone wrong! please be gentle... I'm very new to php.

Thanks in advance

Kaylee

Comment: not a fix but I'd suggest storing a login key in the session, not an id for security reasons and create a random gen salt and hash the password with the salt.

Comment: I take it the session was started. What is the password column length?

Comment: apologies... i just setup the password column as varchar with max of 25 characters...

Comment: you have an answer below, mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"i just setup the password column as varchar with max of 25 characters... – Kaylee"*

There's the problem. `password_hash()` produces a 60 char. length string.

Your present password looks like, and as an example:

`$2y$10$.vGA1O9wmRjrwAVXD9`

As opposed to what it should look like, i.e.:

`$2y$10$.vGA1O9wmRjrwAVXD98HNOgsNpDczlqm3Jq7KnEd1rVAGv3Fykk1a`

> *"Use the bcrypt algorithm (default as of PHP 5.5.0). Note that this constant is designed to change over time as new and stronger algorithms are added to PHP. For that reason, the length of the result from using this identifier can change over time. Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice)."*

- **You need to clear your password rows, alter the column to be 60+ in length, or as the manual suggests, 255 and start over with new hashes.**

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Plus, seeing you are using sessions, make sure it was started inside all pages using sessions.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Check for errors

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Also make sure you don't have a variable scope issue with your functions.

If so, pass db connection to them.

---

**Edit:**

I seem to have missed something and the OP was kind to include it in a comment:

> *"I have now successfully logged in (Yaaay)... had to change $user->redirect() to header(), but it is now working!"*

Comment: downvoter, care to explain here? It's pretty obvious. and care to share your God-given wisdom with the rest of the world?

Comment: Thanks, I'll change that now, hopefully that fixes it!

Comment: Fred -ii- you absolute god you, I have now successfully logged in (Yaaay)... had to change $user->redirect() to header(), but it is now working! thanks again

Comment: @Kaylee Glad to hear it Kaylee, *cheers!* and you're welcome.